# Bind both text field component and file upload control to same richtext field

Tags: xpages, attachment, ssjs

I want to bind text component and file upload control in xpages to same richtext field in backend form. Else i want to save both text and attachments to same richtext field, how can we do it using ssjs. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: @Srujana check this guide and expand your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask